# Difficulty extracting HTML table with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, html-table

I am trying to extract data from the HTML table on the following website: https://fuelkaki.sg/home

[image]

My Python code is as shown below. Pandas is unable to detect the Table. I suspect it is because Beautiful Soup is not able to capture the HTML code on the page properly.

```
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

try:
    url = 'https://fuelkaki.sg/home'
    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.69'}
    page=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
except Exception as e:
    error_type, error_obj, error_info = sys.exc_info()
    print ('ERROR FOR LINK:', url)
    print (error_type, 'Line:', error_info.tb_lineno)
    
time.sleep(2)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')

df = pd.read_html(page.text)
df
```

I have tried using Selenium as well (see code below), but still unable to capture the HTML table information.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://fuelkaki.sg/home'
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"    #chrome binary location specified here
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')


df = pd.read_html(page)
df
```

Any advise would be much appreciated

Comment: It is not an static page you can fetch its data using requests.

Comment: Use something like selenium.

Comment: I have tried using Selenium (see above), but still to no avail

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://fuelkaki.sg/home'
options = Options()

options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "table" })
pd.DataFrame(np.array([x.text.replace('\u202c', '') for x in table.find_all('td')]).reshape(-1,5))
```

Output:

[image]
Please be aware that using website data can be unethical.

Comment: I added "import numpy as np" to the code and it works now. Thanks